# Check child count for the active child objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a parent game object that has 20 child objects. Few of them are active and rest are inactive. How do I check my if statement for the 5 and less active child objects?
Currently it is just counting the child count irrespective active/inactive state of them.

```
void Start () {

        //Active Child count

        if (this.transform.childCount <= 5) {

        }
}
```

Comment: child of the `MonoBehaviour.transform` is `Transform` ... please define "active" and "inactive" transform as `Transform` doesn't have such property

Comment: so how do i check if a total of 5 or less objects are active?

Comment: so what is definition of active for transform? ... basically you need some Linq query like `this.transform.Where(transform=> IsActive(transform)).Count()`

Comment: would it not be transform.gameObject.activeSelf ?

Comment: or `this.transform.Cast<Transform>().Where(transform=> IsActive(transform)).Count()`

Comment: I am getting 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' error.

Comment: @Vika you need `using System.Linq;` and yes it should rather be e.g. `transform.Cast<Transform>().Where(t => t.gameObject.activeSelf).Count();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are into inq you could be unig e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

var count = transform.Cast<Transform>().Where(child => child.gameObject.activeSelf).Coun();
```

For whatever reason [`Transform`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs) only implements the generic [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator#system-collections-ienumerable-getenumerator) so you first have to [`Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast) the results from `object` into `Transform` again. Then you filter only those of [active `GameObject`s](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html) and finally you [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count) those.

---

Or just use the explicit form

```
var count = 0
foreach(Transform child in transform)
{
    if(child.gameObject.activeSelf) count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To ckeck if the a GameObject is active or not use this line:

```
If(myGameObject.activeSelf)
  //Do something if myGameObject is active
```

You have 20 child so you need to loop through all the GameObjects and check if they are active or not.

```
public void checkActive()
    {
        int activeCounter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < parent.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            if(parent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                activeCounter++;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("active gameObjects = " + activeCounter);
    }
```